# Is there any way to find user favorite posts in one query?

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp, paginator

I do this to paginate all posts which a user has added to their favorites:

```
$favs = $this->Favorite->find('all', array(
   'fields' => array(
       'Favorite.post_id'
   ),
   'conditions' => array(
       'Favorite.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')
   )
));
                
$favs = Set::format($favs, '{0}', array('{n}.Favorite.post_id'));
                
$posts = $this->paginate('Post', array(
    'Post.id' => $favs
));
```

Is there any more efficient way to do this or is this like it should be?

Comment: yes, there is.  You need to do an SQL JOIN.  I'd give you an answer but my PHP is far to rusty to do it correctly.  If you don't get an answer ask how to make a JOIN query, or google it.

Comment: if you want a MySQL answer, please include the table layout.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to use `find` method here because `paginate` works pretty much the same way as `find` except for paginating the results.

So you could do what you want by only using `paginate` method.

I doubt that this would increase performance significantly, but it would make your code a bit simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your posts but I found a simple solution yesterday. I hope it'll be helpful for somebody

```
$posts = $this->paginate('Post', array(
  'Post.id IN( (SELECT `Favorite` . `post_id` FROM `favorites` AS `Favorite` WHERE `Favorite`.`user_id` = ' . $this->Auth->user('id') . ') )'
));
```